# vba - Best Practice - Access Form Tab Control List Box Selected Items

Tags: vba, ms-access, tabs

## What works ...

I have an Access I have a form, with a *folder* that has two *pages* or *tabs*. Each of these has it's own combobox related to the tabs topic. I wanted a fairly simply way to do this, by looking into the form, folder, tab I wanted, then pulling all selected values. I didn't know I was going to have to `double for loop` just to get this information.

Regardless, this is my *good enough* solution..

```
Private Sub getComboBoxInsideTabControl()

    Dim selectedPage As Page
    Dim pageIter As Page
    Dim ctrl As Control
    Dim varItm As Variant
    Dim str As String
    Set selectedPage = Me.folder1.Pages(1)

    ' GETS THE CONTROLS ON A PAGE
    For Each ctrl In selectedPage.Controls
        If ctrl.Name = "fields_lb" Then
            MsgBox ("ok...")
            ' SEARCHES THROUGH A COMBOBOX CONTROLS SELECTED ITEMS
            For Each varItm In ctrl.ItemsSelected
            str = str & ctrl.ItemData(varItm) & ","
            Next varItm
        End If
    Next ctrl
    MsgBox (str)

End Sub
```

## What I had hoped for ...

I really just want to know if there is a more simplistic way of doing it. For example, I kind of wanted something like this:

```
Dim results As String
Set results = Me.folder1.Pages(1).Controls("fields_lb").ItemsSelected
```

Is there a better way of doing this I am missing?

Comment: shouldn't you be using listbox instead of combobox?

Comment: this just sounds like it should be a function anyway. Then you get exactly what you want :)

Comment: You "favored" approach should work, as long as you don't declare `results` As String (I think the returned object is a Collection)

Comment: Good catch guys, it is a list box I am talking about. So basically my hypothetical should work, but instead of declaring it as a string I should just do Set results = ... and it will  do it on the fly? Or declare a collection?

Comment: You can just use `Dim results` if you're unsure of the exact type.

Comment: Update: My hypothetical does not work, I have tried it as `Dim results = Me.folder1.Pages(1).Controls("fields_lb").ItemsSelected`